# Can't get config section after update to ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, configuration

I updated my project from 1.0.0-rc1-final to 1.0.0-rc2-final which is called ASP.NET Core 2 now. This is how I initialize the configuration builder:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_CONTENTROOT")).AddJsonFile(file).AddEnvironmentVariables();
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
```

I know for sure that the initialization is ok because I can do

```
configuration.AsEnumerable()
```

in the debugger and see all the values in the configuration files in there.

However, if I try to get a whole configuration section like this

```
configuration.GetSection(section.Name);
```

it doesn't work. It returns an object no matter what I pass to GetSection. However, the *Value* field of this object is always null, regardless whether the section exists or not.

Note that this used to work perfectly fine before.
Any clues?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that one can no longer do something like:

```
var allSettingsInSection = configuration.Get(typeof(StronglyTypedConfigSection), sectionName);
```

Instead, it has to be done like this now:

```
IConfigurationSection sectionData = configuration.GetSection(sectionName);
var section = new StronglyTypedConfigSection();
sectionData.Bind(section);
```

Note that it's necessary to include **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder** in **project.json**.

Comment: Just an update for those who are reading this in 2017 or later. Starting with `ASP.NET Core 2.0`, addition of this extra NuGet is not required.

Comment: I've just done a .Net Core 2.1 app and I **still** need this nuget package, so I don't believe the above comment is correct

Comment: What Liam said - it's still in the _Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder_. But of course you get it in case you are referenceing _Microsoft.AspNetCore.App_ or _Microsoft.AspNetCore.All_.

Comment: You can also simply inject your strongly typed configuration like this:

var jwtSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtSettings));
services.Configure<JwtSettings>(jwtSettingsSection);

Answer (score 8):

Just a cleaner version of the accepted answer:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    services.Configure<MySettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Bind(options));
}
```

[Source](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/)

Answer (score 3):

In dot net core 2.1 you can do this:

I used nameof here to get the name of the class as a string, rather than use an actual string. This is based on Uwe Kleins reply, it's cleaner.

```
var myConfigClass = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyConfigClass)).Get<MyConfigClass>();
```

Easily inject your strongly typed configuration as follows:

```
services.Configure<MyConfigClass>(myConfigClass);
```

Comment: I do like `var MyConfigClass = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyConfigClass)).Get<MyConfigClass>();` to get rid of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the GetSection allot and thus I have created an extension method to help me get sections using generics

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static T GetConfig<T>(this IConfiguration config) where T : new()
    {
        var settings = new T();
        config.Bind(settings);
        return settings;
    }

    public static T GetConfig<T>(this IConfiguration config, string section) where T : new()
    {
        var settings = new T();
        config.GetSection(section).Bind(settings);
        return settings;
    }
}
```